# ListView selected Value C#

Tags: c#, listview

well my code explain everything

```
        if (listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Value First", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
        }
```

but i get this error explained in the picture
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOXMY.png

Comment: You code does NOT explain everyting, Are you using Multi select? or are you just selecting 1 item?

Comment: the user will select 1 item only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there aren't any selected items, then you can't ask for the first one (`listView1.SelectedItems[0]`). In other words, `SelectedItems` is empty.

It seems like you are trying to do something like this. Use `SelectedItems.Count` to check whether or not there is anything in the collection:

```
// if there aren't any selected items
if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count <= 0)
{
   // then give an error
   MessageBox.Show("Please Select Value First", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   return;
}
// otherwise proceed
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set at least 1 selected item on the ListView prior trying to retrieve. 
There is no magic that will do it for you.